# Comparing rows of a multidimesional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, scipy

I have two numpy array

```
a= np.array([[2,2],[3,2],[4,2],[3,3],[5,3]])
b= np.array([[1,1],[1,3],[5,3]])
```

I want to compare a with b and return a-b such that :

```
a-b = array([[2,2],
             [3,2],
             [4,2],
             [3,3]])
```

I have tried doing :

```
[x for x in a if x not in b]
```

and it resulted in

```
[array([2, 2]), array([3, 2]), array([4, 2])] # where clearly [3,3] is missing
```

I even tried comparing each row of both a and b within loop where it gave me an error

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem ???

Comment: Is there any logic behind your output?

Comment: What exactly is the comparison you are trying to do?  It isn't subtraction, it isn't membership, it isn't indexing.  It looks like your output is just the first four elements of `a`.  I am having trouble figuring out how it is related to `b` at all.

Comment: Comparing rows of ' a ' with ' b '.. Return rows of ' a ' which doesn't match with rows of ' b '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to convert the numpy arrays into list of tuples and `b` to set of tuples then do the same list comprehension you used on them. Example -

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a= np.array([[2,2],[3,2],[4,2],[3,3],[5,3]])

In [3]: b= np.array([[1,1],[1,3],[5,3]])

In [18]: alist = list(map(tuple, a))

In [19]: bset = set(map(tuple, b))

In [20]: np.array([x for x in alist if x not in bset])
Out[20]:
array([[2, 2],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) based vectorized approach -

```
a[~((b[:,None,:] == a).all(2)).any(0)]
```

Using [`cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) from [`scipy.spatial.distance`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

a[~(cdist(a,b)==0).any(1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [89]: a
Out[89]: 
array([[2, 2],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [5, 3]])

In [90]: b
Out[90]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 3],
       [5, 3]])

In [91]: a[~((b[:,None,:] == a).all(2)).any(0)]
Out[91]: 
array([[2, 2],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 2],
       [3, 3]])

In [92]: a[~(cdist(a,b)==0).any(1)]
Out[92]: 
array([[2, 2],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```